# Copy table from postgres to local

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I want to copy table from postgis database to the PC hard drive (format can be .txt .xls .csv or whatever).
How it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SQL [**`COPY`** command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) to write to the file system of the database server.

```
COPY tbl TO '/path/to/file/tbl.sql';
```

There are lots of options to adapt the output format.

Have a look at the `\copy` meta-command of [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html) if you need to copy from a remote server to the local disk.